# Google Earth Engine: Join FeatureCollection and List

Tags: javascript, gis, google-earth-engine

I imported a csv called PADDYPOINTS containing the headers below as a FeatureCollection:

`["town","paddy_field","section","longitude","latitude"]`

Then, I extracted NDVI values on each point using the .getRegion() function

```
var PADDYPOINTS = ee.FeatureCollection('users/earthengine/paddy_coordinates');

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_8DAY_NDVI')
  .filterBounds(PADDYPOINTS)
  .filterDate('2017-01-01', '2017-12-31');

var poiArray = dataset.select('NDVI').getRegion(PADDYPOINTS, 30);
```

However getRegion() only returns coordinates: `["id","longitude","latitude","time","NDVI"]` It doesnt return the other columns

How do I join the coordinates from the FeatureCollection above with the getRegion() result to also export the `["town","paddy_field","section"]` columns together as one result?

P.S.: I cant seem to join the original csv with the result using python-pandas as the coordinates are not the same anymore after processing